# Convert pcl xyzrgb(a) point cloud to images from different angles of the cloud

Tags: opencv, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I would like to generate images from my point cloud (Kinect) from different angles, but the only function to take snapshots seems to require an open Viewer (open Window) and saves the images to a file. I would like to process them later and show them in a custom viewer, so storing in RAM is necessary.

Is the point cloud library providing such a method? Or does anybody knows how the approach with pcl would look like?

My second approach is to use opencv mats. Then use the [projectPoints method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints) for the projection, but this works on xyz-coordinates not xyzrgb(a) and I will loose the information which color from the pointcloud point belongs to the new projected image.

I stuck a little bit here :( and hope you can help me :)

Many thanks

Greetings
Carlo

Comment: OpenCV 3.4.0 (if it's built from source) has a namespace cv::viz. This namespace is VTK wrapper (VTK should be installed and configured on your PC before you will build OpenCV). cv::viz gives an opportunity to create custom widgets, that use input data in OpenCV format, but able to use VTK instructions inside. VTK gives an opportunity to project a 3d scene to 2d image. So you will be able to project your 3d point cloud as opencv Point3f array to opencv Mat

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do that using PCL functions. However PCL uses VTK to build it's viewer and I believe you would be able to do what you're talking about by using VTK functionality, though it's likely going to be more complicated. [This article](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/OffScreenRendering) might be a good start.